# Why no Global-Menu support in LibreOffice for 12.04?

Tags: libreoffice

I thought 12.04 was supposed to be a stable bug-fix release? So why are there all these new features in 12.04 and yet long-standing bugs and UI-discrepancies still exist? I'd rather have a Global-Menu in LibreOffice than silly new Dash-lenses and DNSMasq and all the other stuff that should NOT have been added to an LTS release.

Why doesn't LibreOffice have Global-Menu support yet?

Comment: If you want to enable it see this post http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/04/enable-global-menu-for-libreoffice-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/

Answer (score 2):

The reason for not including global-menu in libreoffice was that there were too many issues remaining and the [development team](http://sweetshark.livejournal.com/11119.html) basically ran out of time & resources.

> Unfortunately, resource constrains did not allow this to happen, so
>   this was postponed to the quantal release. The planning will be done
>   at UDS-Q beginning of May

From this blue-print you can see the open issues:

https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/desktop-p-libreoffice-lo-menubar-polish

Thus - you can install `lo-menubar` - but it will give you issues as described.

Possibly the 12.10 release of libreoffice will be available either as a backport or via a PPA and thus global menu integration will be completed ... at this stage this is speculative though.

Answer (score 1):

To enable Global Menu for LibreOffice, install [lo-menubar [image: Install lo-menubar]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/lo-menubar), either in the Software Center by  clicking that link, or in the Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) by running these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lo-menubar
```

Comment: Just a word of caution to the OP, I started having issues with LibreOffice after installing lo-menubar. I could not use print preview without crashing the system, but after removing it the problem went away.